# When I use C# callback function in VBA it shows "entry point not found "

Tags: c#, vba, callback

I want to use C# callback function in VBA. But when I call C# function it shows "entry point not found "

How can I fix it?
Thanks

PS:I checked Make assembly COM-Visible and Register for COM inter
Environment:MS Office Excel 2007, MS Visual Studio 2008

**VBA code:**

```
Declare Function Result Lib"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\myprog\New_DLL_Test\New_DLL_Test\bin\Debug\New_DLL_Test.dll" Alias "Msg" (ByVal p As Long) As Integer

Function Disp()
   MsgBox x
End Function

Sub AddResult(ByVal p As Long)
    Dim x As Long   
    x = Result(p)
    Debug.Print x
End Sub

Sub testnow_Click()
    Call AddResult(AddressOf Disp)
End Sub
```

**C# code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace New_DLL_Test
{
    [Guid("f1286974-0f1a-466c-8389-dd1ab7e3eed2"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    interface Msginterface
    {
        int Msg;
    }
    public unsafe class MsgProcess
    {
        public int Msg(int* p)
        {
           return add(p,1);
        }
        public int add(int* p, int j)
        {
            return j+1;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A VBA declare function allows you to access a stdcall function exported from a DLL. A COM visible class and interface are a completely different thing. Although the two methods can work together, a function acting as an unmanaged export can return a com visible object. Or each method can be used independently of the other.

### Calling Static C# Functions From VBA

If you want to write the VBA code that way, and access the DLL like that you need to create an unmanaged export from your C# project. I believe there are two ways to do this. One is to manually create a wrapper in managed C++ that exports the function. The other would be to use a compile-time build task and library like [UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports).

### Using a COM Visible C# Object from VBA

To use the C# class through the COM interop you need to register your C# assembly using regasm.exe then create the object in VBA using the CreateObject function. Both the class and the interface need to be COM visible. [You can find a very basic tutorial here](http://adamprescott.net/2012/04/05/net-vb6-interop-tutorial/).

Comment: A downvote without any comment? Well that's useless. This is a topic of interest to me, so I'd love to know how I'm wrong or better methods.

Comment: I should have downvoted the question, instead of the answer. On a review of the question, it's unclear but well answered. The answer just appeared to be incomplete at the time, as I was looking for an answer that covered other aspects of the integration, like threading.